# Jquery - Each parent element, remove and clone child el

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's sort of working, I just get the element I'm cloning more than once.

When the browser hits mobile size, I want my JS to switch elements around, like this.

**From:**

```
<div class="sar--img-right-first">
   <div class="sar--first">text</div>
   <div class="sar--second">img</div>
</div>
<div class="">
   <div class="">img</div>
   <div class="">text</div>
</div>
<div class="sar--img-right-first">
   <div class="sar--first">text</div>
   <div class="sar--second">img</div>
</div>
```

**To:**

```
<div class="sar--img-right-first">
       <div class="sar--second">img</div>
       <div class="sar--first">text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="">
       <div class="">img</div>
       <div class="">text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sar--img-right-first">
       <div class="sar--second">img</div>
       <div class="sar--first">text</div>
    </div>
```

**But currently it gives me:**

```
<div class="sar--img-right-first">
   <div class="sar--second">img</div>
   <div class="sar--second">img</div>
   <div class="sar--second">img</div>
   <div class="sar--first">text</div>
</div>
<div class="">
   <div class="">img</div>
   <div class="">text</div>
</div>
<div class="sar--img-right-first">
   <div class="sar--second">img</div>
   <div class="sar--second">img</div>
   <div class="sar--first">text</div>
</div>
```

**My code:**

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        if(jQuery(window).width() <= 1000) {

            jQuery( ".sar--img-right-first").each(function() {
               var thiz = jQuery(this);

               thiz.find(".sar--second").remove().clone().insertBefore(".sar--first"); 
             });

        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include the HTML structure

Comment: Please show relevant html and expected results as per [mcve]

Comment: You should definitely be using CSS media queries for this instead of JavaScript.

Comment: well ".sar--first" is not looking just in the element you are in.... hint hint

Comment: You don't need to `.remove().clone()` to `.insertBefore()` just make the call and jquery will *move* the item for you, here's a mini fiddle to demonstrate:  https://jsfiddle.net/tk6wz5hs/  (issue with `.class` selecting all the same elements aside ofc)

Comment: I'll never understand why some questions are voted closed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close.  But you don't need to use the remove or clone functions.  Here's a simple working example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 1000) {
    $(".sar--img-right-first").each(function() {
        $(this).find('.sar--second').insertBefore($(this).find('.sar--first'));
    });
  }
});
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Le36x1qw/1/)

Comment: Thanks @CrazyPaste
This did the job!

Answer (score 0):

When you call `.insertBefore(".sar--first")`, it is finding *all* those elements and inserting before each one.  I think you can accomplish what you want by looking for the parent to restrict your search for the element to insert before.  Also you don't need to use [`clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/), [`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) returns the removed element.  In fact you might want to use [`detach()`](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) to keep any event handlers and data associated with those elements if you're just rearranging them.

```js
$('.p3').each(function() {
  var ele = $(this);
  var sib = ele.parent().find('.p1');
  var det = ele.detach();
  det.insertBefore(sib);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<p class="p1">p1</p>
<p class="p2">p2</p>
<p class="p3">p3</p>
</div>
<h3>Second Set</h3>
<div>
<p class="p1">p1</p>
<p class="p2">p2</p>
<p class="p3">p3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need explicit detach, just insertBefore. It will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you really just want to swap divs when Window size is less than 1000.  Try this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    if (jQuery(window).width() <= 1000) {
        jQuery(".sar--second").each(function () {
            var previousSibling = jQuery(this).prev();
            jQuery(this).prev().remove();
            jQuery(this).append(previousSibling);                    
        });
    }            
});
```